# Rspec failed for input field in view spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

I create a view file using haml like below

```
.panel-table
  %table.table-form
    %tr
      %th.table-form__head 
        %label.header-sub.form-label{ 'for': 'mail_auto_group_name' }
          配信タイトル
          .required-icon 必須
      %td.table-form__data
        .form-input
          #mail_auto_group_name= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-input__text', placeholder: '配信タイトル'
```

My spec file is like below:

```
context 'When the input value is normal' do
    before do
      visit new_client_project_mail_auto_group_path(project)

      fill_in 'mail_auto_group[name]', with: 'New title'
      first('.nice-select.form-input__select').click
      page.all('.option')[1].click
      find('#saveMailAuto').click
    end

    scenario 'The distribution title registered in the distribution list is displayed' do
      expect(page).to have_content 'New title'
    end
  end
```

But this spec is failed & shows text not found.

The error is like below:

> Failure / Error: expect (page) .to have_content'new title'
> expected to find text "new title" in "project 3 \ ntest_user3 \ narrow_drop_down \ n mail delivery (automatic) \ n automatic delivery
> creation \ n <automatic delivery list \ n delivery title required \ n
> extraction condition required \ ntest condition \ n Measure group 
> nPlease select \ nMail delivery \ nSelect a template \ nSubject
> Mandatory \ nHTML body Mandatory \ n1 \ n2 \ n3 \ nBody \ nLINE
> delivery \ nDelivery interval (day) Mandatory \ nDelivery interval
> Please enter (day) \ nFirst delivery start date and time Required 
> nDelivery count optimization \ nAutomatic ON / OFF \ nDelivery time
> optimization \ nDelivery delay time (minutes) Required \ n0 \ nIgnore
> blacklist \ n Extraction interval (minutes) Required \ n5 \ nPriority
> Required \ n0 \ nIP POOL \ nDefault \ nEnable test mode \ nSelect
> delivery list \ nsend \ nTest delivery \ nhome \ nProject home 
> nemail \ nMail delivery (automatic) \ nAutomatic delivery list 
> nActivity \ nExtraction condition setting \ nMeasures group setting 
> ntouch_app \ nMail delivery (manual) \ nManual delivery list 
> nDelivery list management \ nweb \ nTemplate management \ nTemplate
> list \ nsend \ nTest distribution \ nTest distribution list 
> nsettings \ nSettings \ nCompany information \ nUser management 
> nProject management \ nAccount \ nBlacklist "

I can't figure out why my spec fails.

Comment: `visit new_client_project_mail_auto_group_path(project)` there is a project variable in there, are you creating the factory before you pass to the route? It seems that you're not displaying the `name` value on the page. Could you share your controller?

Comment: There are two general ways this could be failing: your form submission failed and name is not on the page, or your form submission succeeded and name is not on the page. Can you rule out one of these?

Comment: @JakeWorth It seems like name is not on the page

Comment: @Animesh it sounds like your form submission is failing. You'll need to read or debug through the controller action to figure out how.

Comment: @Animesh Look at your `test.log` to see why the submission is failing. Additionally to make your tests more resilient you should specify a minimum on the `all` call if you're going to be indexing on the results  `page.all('.option', minimum: 2)[1].click`